# Python - turn off wifi with MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

The following Python script will be run with MonkeyRunner:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner, MonkeyView, MonkeyImage

my_device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

activity = "android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS"
my_device.startActivity(action=activity)
```

The WiFi setting will pop up on the screen.

How can check what the ***WiFi status*** is?
And in case it is turned on, how can turn it off?

It can be done with an ADB command:

```
wifistate = os.popen("adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop wlan.driver.status")
```

But how can it be done without opening a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script, that can be generated automatically using **[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** and then being slightly edited to handle the **ON/OFF** case does exactly what you need:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2014  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2014-12-05 by Culebra v8.18.1
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'startviewserver': True, 'forceviewserveruse': False, 'autodump': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 1, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'do-not-verify-initial-screen-dump': True, 'use-regexps': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'use-jar': False, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': True, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'output': '/Users/diego/tmp/settings-wifi.py', 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'Wi.Fi')).touch()
        self.vc.sleep(CulebraTests.sleep)
        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        try:
            self.assertIsNotNone(self.vc.findViewWithText(u'OFF'))
        except:
            self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'ON').touch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

I created it using `culebra` GUI, clicking on the **Wi-Fi** item, checking the state using culebra's CTRL-T, and clicking on the toggle. Then I manually edit it to add the `try/except` block for **ON/OFF**.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get just the WiFi status.
Is it possible to do somehow with:
activity = "android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS"
my_device.startActivity(action=activity)

Comment: Yes, try `culebra --help` and you'll see `-a, --start-activity=COMPONENT   starts Activity before dump`